# Thread: 505.50 when using custom rewrite provider (the one from samples)

Tags: sql, iis-7, provider, url-rewrite-module

I'd like to know how to troubleshoot IIS URL Rewrite module and custom rewrite providers?

I am trying to do a POC on the URL Rewrite Module for our app. Our mappings are all in the database so I thought using the provider that comes as a sample. Got everything installed and configured, as instructed. Created the stored procedure as well. Now when I hit the alias URL I receive HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error. Here are the details about the error:

Module RewriteModule
Notification BeginRequest
Handler ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code 0x80070585

In SQL Profiler I see no calls to my stored procedure. The app pool is running under my account (admin rights). No errors in the event logs.

Are there any logs I could look into for more information on what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after two days of digging. The samples are good but not good enough: simply using supplied DLLs with supplied config entries doesn't work (for many reasons).

What I ended up doing was getting rid of the DLLs from samples and creating my own provider using the source code from samples and information from this article: [Developing a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/). Then IIS started loading my provider. But in order to make it work correctly I had to get deep understanding of module's config system.

So my answer to my own question -- don't relay on samples alone, they don't work out of the box. Instead, RTFM :) The best place to start is here: [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/)